# OpenSearch Dashboard: Normalize By Unit - How to achieve this aggregation similar to ELK

Tags: amazon-opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I am creating a chart where X axies has time histogram and on Y axies I want to plot different lines per API indicating requests / min hits for that particular API. I created this in ELK using tis technique shown in the attached diagram. But not able to do this OpenSearch.

[image]